bcrypt.compare() devuelve "false" siempre
estoy realizando un sistema auth en Nodejs, y me he encontrado con el error de que la función bcrypt.compare() siempre devuelve false. EL código que estoy utilizando es este:
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['user', 'admin'],
      default: 'user'
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Hash the password before saving it to the database
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
});




userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password) {
 if(bcrypt.compare(password, this.password) === "true"){
  return true;
 } else { 
  return false;
 }
 
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;

los console.logs de que he realizado me han llevado a que el error se encuentra aquí, pero no consigo dar con la solución.
la contraseña con la que estoy haciendo el testeo es:
Plaintext: test
Hash: $2b$10$e2KuxFiAq4oVl7DaL80TX.9udp65K9uoiVOSfXZNmzHP8rVqIR5bG
y así es como se está almacenando en MongoDB:
{"_id":{"$oid":"66408f417315a786f0d1d279"},"username":"test","email":"test@mail.com","password":"$2b$10$e2KuxFiAq4oVl7DaL80TX.9udp65K9uoiVOSfXZNmzHP8rVqIR5bG","role":"user","createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1715507009424"}},"updatedAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1715507009424"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

Agradecería mucho que me ayudaran a resolver este problema.
Un saludo :D

No necesitas un if/else para devolver un booleano cuando el método ya devuelve un boolean de por si. Además, los triple iguales comparan no solo el valor si no el TIPO. "true" nunca va a ser igual a true así puesto que uno es boolean y el otro string. Simplemente haz un return bcript.compare(... y ya está. Hacer if (true) return true; else return false; es totalmente innecesario!

@Benito-B He hecho eso, me sigue dando false. He hecho una función a parte para comprobar si es un error a lo mejor de como se pasa la contraseña y lo he comprobado con una contraseña almacenada en la db, sigue dando false. También he cambiado de la version 5.1.1 a la 5.1.0, nada ha resultado efecto.

Si debugas un poco tu código, cuando invocas a compare qué le estás pasando? El primer parámetro debería ser la contraseña en texto plano, y la segunda el hash.

Si, lo de debugeado y ya está mas que comprobado que primero se compara la contraseña introducida por el usuario y luego el HASH.

bcrypt.compare() ya retorna un valor booleano, al comparar su resultado con === de javascript, verifica el tipo de dato y el valor, en ese caso "true", es decir, compara string y el valor string true, por lo que no seran iguales.
La correcion seria la siguiente:


userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password) {
 return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};




He hecho las modificaciones que me has dicho, pero sigue devolviendo "False" Aunque la contraseña sea correcta.
